# Insert into Database when all the tasks of ThreadPoolExecutor have finished executing there jobs

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

**Problem Definiton:-**

I need to `insert some values into Database` as soon as all the tasks of `ExecutorService` have finished exectuing there jobs. In other words, I can `insert into database` only when all the tasks have finished executing there jobs as the things that I need to insert into db, is dependent on all the threads finishing there tasks..

**So how I can check whether all the tasks of `ExecutorService` have been finished executing and then start inserting into database.**

Below is the code in which I am creating task using `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

```
executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
    noOfThreads, 
    noOfThreads, 
    500L, 
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
    new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(noOfThreads), 
    new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy()
);


// Running for particular duration of time
while(System.currentTimeMillis() <= endTime) {
    Command newCommand = getNextCommand();
    Task nextRunnable = new Task(newCommand, existId, newId);
    executorService.submit(nextRunnable); // Submit it for execution
}

/* 
    Previously I was inserting into database here, but it was wrong as it might be 
    possible that some threads are still in progress. And If I am inserting right here 
    into database, then some information I will be loosing for sure. So how can I check 
    whether all the tasks have finished executing and then I can insert into database.
*/      
executorService.shutdown();
if (!executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS)) {
    executorService.shutdownNow();
}
```

The code that I will be using for insertion is below-

```
// Inserting into Database when all the task have finished executing, currently I
for (Entry<Integer, LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>> entry : GUID_ID_MAPPING.entrySet()) {
    pstatement = db_connection.prepareStatement(LnPConstants.UPSERT_SQL);
    pstatement.setInt(1, entry.getKey());
    pstatement.setString(2, entry.getValue().get(LnPConstants.CGUID_ID));
    pstatement.setString(3, entry.getValue().get(LnPConstants.PGUID_ID));
    pstatement.executeUpdate();
}
```

So I need to put this for loop somewhere after all the tasks have finished executing.

**Update:-**

So Something like this-

```
executorService.shutdown();
if (!executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS)) {
    executorService.shutdownNow();
}

// Now Insert into Database when all the task have finished executing
for (Entry<Integer, LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>> entry : GUID_ID_MAPPING.entrySet()) {
    pstatement = db_connection.prepareStatement(PDSLnPConstants.UPSERT_SQL);
    pstatement.setInt(1, entry.getKey());
    pstatement.setString(2, entry.getValue().get(PDSLnPConstants.CGUID_ID));
    pstatement.setString(3, entry.getValue().get(PDSLnPConstants.PGUID_ID));
    pstatement.executeUpdate();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically have the answer already.  Wait for `executorService.awaitTermination` to return, and the executor will have completed all it's tasks.

This ignores tasks that may have failed due to an error.  Another way to do this, and to check for errors is to do something like,

```
 List<Future> futures = ...
 for(...) {
      futures.add(executor.submit(...));
 }

 for(Future f : futures) {
       //this will throw an exception if an exception
       //occurred executing the task, insert error handling as 
       //appropriate, perhaps calling cancel on tasks that
       //have not yet completed
       f.get();
 }
 //at this point all tasks have completed
```

Another class to look at is [ExecutorCompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html).  ExecutorCompletionService allows you to get tasks in the order that they actually complete.

Comment: Thanks sbridges for the sugegstion. So where should I start inserting into databse? Can you provide an example basis on my code, so that I can understand more what you just said to me.

Comment: After the  executorService.awaitTermination line

Comment: Just updated my question with the way you suggested me, Can you take a look and suggest me whether that's the right way?

Comment: That should work.  The other way I suggested, using a List of Futures will allow you to reuse the same thread pool, and not call awaitTermination

Answer (score 2):

seems like good use case to use ExecutorCompletionService ,have you thought about it ? 
[Check JavaDoc for ExecutorCompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) 
You can do something like this

```
//wrap your threadpoolexecutor ECS
ExecutorCompletionService<Boolean> ecs=new ExecutorCompletionService<Boolean>(executorService)
// submit task to ECS
ecs.submit(nextRunnable);
int noOfTasks=0;
// Running for particular duration of time
while(System.currentTimeMillis() <= endTime) {
    Command newCommand = getNextCommand();
    Task nextRunnable = new Task(newCommand, existId, newId);
    ecs.submit(nextRunnable, Boolean.TRUE); // Submit it for execution
    noOfTasks++;
    }
//Now we can use ECS to tell us what tasks are finished
for (int i=0;i<noOfTasks;i++){
 try {    
 //This is blocking call it would block until anyone of the task submitted is completed.
   Boolean result=ecs.take.get();
 // do something if you would like to handle result, you can also design to pass some unique id       instead of Boolean so that you can keep track of what tasks are completed
     }catch(ExecutionException e){//do error handling for task failure here}
     }
  //once you are here you are sure that all tasks are completed, call your database code here, you can wrap whole segment into try catch finally and close ExecutorCompletionservie
```